# import mod from another package

Tags: python, import

How do I import mod1 from ccc.py?

I have the following dir and files:

```
proj/
|- aaa/
  |- bbb/
    |- ccc.py
|- ddd/
  |- __init__.py
  |- eee/
    |- __init__.py
    |- mod1.py
    |- fff.py
  |- ggg/
    |- __init__.py
    |- mod2.py
```

Comment: mod1 is func or class ?

Comment: mod1 is a py file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:‌

```
from proj.aaa.bbb.ccc import mod1
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your tree files;

you should write in your ccc.py file:

```py
from proj.ddd.eee import mod1
```

or if you want to import everything:

```py
from proj.ddd.eee.mod1 import *
```

Comment: Thanks. I also want to know how to invoke the ccc.py without import error.